# how to slide horizontal view as uisubview in ipad

Tags: ipad, uiview

i have a task to develop book application for ipad. and it is having the function like the image i have posted in my post.

And i have task to develop the sub view on button click as the sub view of mainview in center of screen.

I have to develop view [image: Like this which is given in the image.]. Please help me and provide some hint about how to develop the view like above screen shot.

And please provide some example or sample code for it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain what you want to do in a more detailed way. Is the view holding your book covers the view which should be slidable? Or should the view, which contains the "featured books" view be the one that's slidable?

Comment: @JohannesLumpe i want to create the view which is holding book covers that view will be slidable on "featured books" button click.

Comment: Are you creating your layout in Interface Builder or in code?

Comment: @JohannesLumpe thanks for reply, but i am creating only one layout. and their is no any other layout. and i have no idea about how to create this type of view. in ipad.

Comment: See my answer. On a note: you would handle this the same on iPhone. A scrollview is available on both devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a UIScrollview, which has paging enabled. (can be done either in Interface Builder or in code). Assign it to a property inside your viewcontroller. It could look like this:

```
 // this is how it looks when you do it in code yourself
@property (weak,nonatomic) UIScrollView *theScrollView;

// this is how it looks when you let Interface Builder create your property for you
@property(weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *theScrollView;
```

Notice that the property is weak. Because your view is added to your viewcontrollers main view as a subview, that view already has a strong pointer to it, so you don't need your property to be strong. If you want to be able to remove add readd your scrollview from your main view, then you should use a strong pointer, or else your scrollview will get deallocated.

Now, in code, add your subviews to it, with proper incrementing x-offset and then when you tap the button have a function like this handling the tap:

```
/* i assume your scrollview is a property on your viewcontroller with the name "theScrollView */
- (void) handleFeaturedTap
{
    /* 
    get the offset of your subview, to which you want to scroll, not shown.
    */
    [self.theScrollView scrollRectToVisible:theRectYouWantToShow animated:YES];
}
```

This will then have the scrollview slide to your desired area, which in your case would be the position where you added your view which holds the featured books.

If you are unsure on how to create a UIScrollview in code or through Interface Builder I suggest you read http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html and the UIView reference aswell and check out some tutorials on how to use Interface Builder.

Comment: Thanks for you reply but i cant understand that how  should i create the view on featured book button like above image. and please provide some code in deep so i can under stand it.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? You don't know how to create a button? Or you don't know how to create a view at all? Have you worked with Interface Builder before? Is this your first iOS application?